How can I control my spesific mapOf element?
I have a mapOf name of wordList and I am getting random keys from it. I have a control button and editText. When user write the key's value and click the control button, I will do some things. How can I check the value of the random key?
val wordList = mapOf("onekey" to "onevalue" , "twokey" to "twovalue" , "threekey" to "threevalue")


Please [edit] your question and specify what you want to achieve. Do you just want to know how to get a random key of wordList? Or is it something else?

I got it done folks. If you want to get your mapOf's value, you can get like this. ("randomWordText" is my a "TextView" for my random keys from my "mapOf")
wordList[binding.randomWordText.text.toString()]


What does binding.randomWordText.text.toString() do exactly?

My wordList's spesific element. I am getting this element from my random word text and doing some things.

You can achieve this by creating a function to get a random key from the map
fun getRandomKey(map: Map<String, String>): String? {
    if (map.isEmpty()) return null
    val keys = map.keys.toList()
    return keys.random()
}

set an onClickListener, call getRandomKey when the button is clicked, and display the random key and its value
     val controlButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.controlButton)

     controlButton.setOnClickListener {
            val randomKey = getRandomKey(wordList)
            randomKey?.let {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Random Key: $randomKey, Value: ${wordList[randomKey]}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }


Thanks but I am done about getting a random key.  I want to check the random key's value whether it is true.
